# Add Button on top of a bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am trying to add a button on top of my bootstrap table.
In my Table a enabled the search option.
After I added the button, I have a table, on the top of the table on the right side I have my search line, And on top of it on the top left side I have my button.

How can I align my button with the search line?

[image: image of the site]

The code:

```
<div className="Object-table">
        <DropdownButton className="dropdown-toggle"
                            type="button"
                            bsStyle={"btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"}
                            class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg dropdown-toggle"
                            onSelect={this.onFilterChange}
                            title={this.state.onObjectFilter}
                            id="objectNameFilter"
            >
                <MenuItem eventKey={["All"]}>All</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem eventKey={["Objec1"]}>Objec1</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem eventKey={["Objec2"]}>Objec2</MenuItem>

            </DropdownButton>
            <BootstrapTable data={rows} striped={true} hover={true}  
options={this.state.options} trClassName={trClassFormat} search={true} >
```

Comment: So what is the css behind this?

Comment: for the button only the bsStyle  (i didn't added objectNameFilter to my style.css) and for the BootstrapTable i have trClassFormat that return a style according to some situation - the only different in the text color. for example:     color: blue;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;